# Cruise Control .NET 4.0 MSBUILD Logger

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0, cruisecontrol.net, logging

Has anyone gotten a MSBuild task in Cruise Control to load a logger?

I've tried variations but it always fails to load the logger.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
C:\builds\MVC2Test\trunk\MVC2Test\MVC2Test.sln
/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=CruiseControl /v:diag
Build
15

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger, C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll

Please post a working exclusively .NET 4.0 example if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, getting .NET 4.0 and Cruise Control .NET going came down to this:

1)  Avoid 64 bit MSBuild like the plague... have a working 32 bit build first.

2)  Just specify the fully qualified path to the logger, not the typical class, 
assembly format.

3)  Deploy the targeting pack from the VS 2010 disc. \WCU\MTPack\NetFx_DTP.msi EXTUI=1 /log install.log

4)  Always prove MSBuild works from the command line first.

5)  Create a configuration in your solution file and include only the projects you want to build

```
<msbuild>
    <!-- WARNING:  You must copy the files from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications to the same path on your build server -->
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\builds\SOLUTIONFOLDER\trunk\</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>C:\builds\SOLUTIONFOLDER\trunk\SOLUTIONNAME.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=CruiseControl /v:diag</buildArgs>
    <targets>Build</targets>
    <timeout>15</timeout>
    <logger>C:\CruiseControl\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```

Now if Microsoft would only let us easily install MSTest on our Build Servers...  People have been begging for 5 years, how can Microsoft have learned so little about testing?

Good luck all.

Comment: +1 for the point about MSTest. We had to install VS on our build server and that is just plain goofy. I suppose it is because they want us to use TFS Build server but it is so immature right now that CCNet is far better choice.