# CruiseControl.NET MSBuild Logger for .NET 4

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-4.0, cruisecontrol.net, logging

I just upgraded to .NET 4 from 3.5 and now am having issues getting build results to display on the cruisecontrol.net web dashboard. Before it would display build errors, using the [Rodemeyer.MSBuildToCCNet.dll](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Improved+MSBuild+Integration).

This dll doesn't seem to work with .NET 4 so I went back to using the standard ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll logger but still am not having any success. When I view the build results webpage it just shows that it failed but doesn't give any build errors. I have to then view the build log, which shows that msbuild tried to compile the solution but generated errors.

Anyone know of a cc.net logger that actually works with .NET 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cruise Control .NET 4.0 MSBUILD Logger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691436/cruise-control-net-4-0-msbuild-logger)

Comment: I read that post before posting my own and the suggested steps didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Visual Studio Unit Tests in your solution? I know that CCNET 1.5 has a logged issue regarding reporting unit test results.

Comment: I do have visual studio unit tests in my solution, which are run via mstest. I don't see them on the build results page, so that IS an issue, however I also don't see build errors even so the scope of my issue is larger than that.

Comment: @Justin, I'm working on the same issue. I'll let you know what I come up with when I get it working.

Comment: Supposedly, this has been resolved for 1.6: http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1957

Comment: I was using 1.6 but still had issues, however I'm wondering if I had forgotten to include those 2 mentioned xsl files and maybe that was the issue. Anyway, I switched from cruisecontrol to teamcity and also switched from mstest to nunit, and those two moves made my life much easier.

Answer (score -1):

Justin, i think best bet to check out the release notes for the version you have issue :

http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/CCNet%201.4.4%20Release%20Notes.html

[link text](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/CCNet%201.4.4%20Release%20Notes.html)

I tried with this version, works in my case; My suggestion rollback to 3.5 if doesn't work till fix released.

Comment: Rolling back to 3.5 just because cruisecontrol doesn't show the build results on the webpage would be ridiculous...

Comment: Agreed. Changing your project to facilitate your build environment is never a good idea.